# if i remove dash from uuid v4 will id still be unique

Tags: uuid

I am using uuid v4 to create id for my mysql table. when generate uuid using uuid v4 it alway have 4 dash. I want to remove these dash to make the uuid more beauty. But i don't know if it's safe to remove these dash (is it still unique uuid)?

Comment: Short answer: yes.They follow [a set pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format), that's why.

Comment: Removing the dashes does not affect the uniqueness of the UUIDs you generate.  But storing a string UUID in your database table is not ideal from a storage point of view.

Comment: Thank you guy :). @TimBiegeleisen i know that use integer for id will create more high performance on search. but when show to outside world i will have to show something like :http://example/get/id=23772362 and my boss doesn't like it. he want id show to outside world must be something else. I don't know what a better way :'(

Comment: You could store the UUID strings with dashes, and then just remove them when you query for displaying results.  If you plan on using the UUIDs somewhere you would probably want the original format.

Comment: i'l do it. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As UUID are always 16byte numbers, the “content“ is independent of the string representation. If it is convenient for your special application and have a bijective mapping you can convert the UUID as you need. Any mapping of the 128bit is technically possible.
The common representation (mapping) is given by RFC 4122 which includes the dashes.